# Defining user-defined getters in a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

My question relates to Vue and more specifically reactivity and reactive getter/setters: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Can I define my own getters in a Vue component and what will happen to them when Vue add its own reactive getters?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Stephan-v I come from an angular background and I frequently use **getters** in my angular components in order to access my component properties without invoking a method. Hence my question.

Comment: You can use computed properties for that. They are cached for re-usage and you can add a `setter` as well. Look for the section of `computed setter` for a how to here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Thanks. I am reading the documentation you pointed me to.

Comment: Out of curiosity and quite independently of best practices, what would happen if a developper defined his own user-defined getter in a Vue component?

Comment: The outcome of a self-defined getter method would not be cached so I you do anything other than simple return a reference value straight away, it would be a performance hit. Since Vue already attaches getters and setters to your data properties to set up data binding it would also simply abstract your code without any benefits.

Comment: What do you mean by *it would also simply abstract your code* ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173871/discussion-between-stephan-v-and-balteo).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Vue will walk through all of its properties and convert them to getter/setters using Object.defineProperty

What the above sentence means is vue iterates over each property in your `data` option to make them reactive.

For example consider your `data` option to be:

```
data:{
  foo: 'hello world',
  bar: 3
}
```

vue will override the `data` object as follows(just an abstract description):

```
let key = Object.keys(data)

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  let val = data[keys[i]];
  Object.defineProperty(data, keys[i], {
    get(){
      // add this property as a dependency when accessed
      return val;
    },
    set(newVal){
      //notify for a change
      val = newVal;
    }
  })
}
```

If you check out the vue [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/observer/index.js#L143) for the same you will find that it checks whether the properties have [predefined getters or setters](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/observer/index.js#L148).

Then it overrides the properties getter as follows:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  get: function reactiveGetter() {
    const value = getter ? getter.call(obj) : val;
    if (Dep.target) {
      dep.depend();
      if (childOb) {
        childOb.dep.depend();
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
          dependArray(value);
        }
      }
    }
    return value;
  },
  set(newVal) {
    //...
  }
});
```

If you see this [*line*](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/observer/index.js#L160) `const value = getter ? getter.call(obj) : val;`
 you'll notice that if you defined a getter it is being used and is its value returned.

Vue is just doing some more work to make them reactive by invoking some dependency related methods thats it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive reply! I really appreciate.

Comment: I was also looking for some more explanaition. You did a great job. Tnx!