# Trying to understand this Vue reactivity inconsistency

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

I am confused... Given the following two examples:

#### Example 1: https://jsfiddle.net/luckylooke/rbzwme91/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Hello!",
    myPropInternal: 0,
  },
  computed: {
    myProp: {
      // getter
      get: function () {
      console.log('get', this.myPropInternal);
      return this.myPropInternal;
      },
      // setter
      set: function (value) {
      console.log('set', value);
      this.myPropInternal = value;
      }
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.myProp = 1;
    this.myProp = 2;
    this.myProp = 3;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <h1>{{ message }} - {{ myProp }}</h1>
</div>
```

#### Example 2: https://jsfiddle.net/luckylooke/9khzv7a1/8/

```js
const myObject = {
    myPropInternal: 0,
  get myProp() {
      console.log('get', this.myPropInternal);
      return this.myPropInternal;
  },
  set myProp(value) {
      console.log('set', value);
      this.myPropInternal = value;
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Hello!",
    myObject
  },
  created: function() {
    this.myObject.myProp = 1;
    this.myObject.myProp = 2;
    this.myObject.myProp = 3;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <h1>{{ message }} - {{ myObject.myProp }}</h1>
</div>
```

Example 1 results in this console log:

```
"set", 1
"set", 2
"set", 3
"get", 3
```

I would expect that every change of a model would cause a computed value (getter) to evaluate, like it is in Example 2, where the output is:

```
"get", 0
"get", 0
"set", 1
"get", 1
"set", 2
"get", 2
"set", 3
"get", 3
```

Why does Vue not react immediately on every change in first example?

Comment: Computeds are optimized to not be triggered for same values.

Comment: I gotta say that I 100% forgot that [computed setters](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) exist.

Comment: @EstusFlask I agree, but 1,2,3 are not same ;)

Comment: iirc this is a vue optimization, I'll try and find the source.

Comment: Even if it is an optimalisation it is optimised on wrong place as second Example is bypassing it  :/

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's going on here, backed by what I've been able to gather from the awesome [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/), some helpful research, and some quick experimentation.

The crux of what you're calling a "reactivity difference" lies in how Vue makes properties in `data` reactive, and how Vue treats `computed` properties *differently* than those in `data`.

#### Vue Reactivity

First, let's establish how Vue makes a `data` property reactive, which pertains directly to Example #2.

When you add a property to `data` in Vue, Vue does some pre-processing work before render to make this property *reactive*. I won't do a deep-dive about this process here, but the gist is that Vue replaces your data properties with a series of getters and setters internally. These getters and setters allow Vue to track *what* data changes/ is accessed, *when* it changes/ is accessed, and *in what context* it's changing or being accessed in ([this is how `computed` properties discover their reactive dependencies and know they're stale](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-do-computed-properties-know-how-to-change/24140/2)). Vue uses this data to update the DOM accordingly when a relevant dependency changes.

For example, if you have `<div>{{ str }}</div>` as a node in your template with a `str` field in `data`, based on the processing that Vue does before render, when the value of `str` changes, Vue will detect this change and trigger a DOM update, and will ultimately patch a changed/ new node into the DOM, updating what you see on the page.

More about this process can be found [on the Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html), and I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476619/how-does-vue-js-reactivity-work-under-the-hood/54492326#54492326) to be a nice rundown too.

#### Computed Properties

Computed properties aren't "reactive" in the same way as `data` properties are, because `computed` properties don't store data. They're more akin to watchers, and can be thought about like methods that trigger automatically when needed.

The difference I most want to highlight here between `computed` props and `data` properties is that *`computed` props only recalculate when necessary*. In other words, they only recalculate when they're invoked, either manually in a method/ lifecycle hook/ other property, or by being a dependency in the DOM (eg. `<div>{{ computedProp }}</div>`). If you had a computed prop that was completely unused in your component's script and unreferenced in the rendered DOM, it would *never* run, even when its dependencies changed.

This explains the discrepancy seen between your examples, because instead of changing a `data` prop directly, you're proxying the change through a `computed` prop, which isn't running its getter function until it needs to– in this case, that's when the component finally mounts, and the computed prop is referenced by a node in the DOM.

So to answer your question directly:

> Why does Vue not react immediately on every change in first example?

It's not reacting because there's nothing to react to– it's storing the value when you invoke the setter, but Vue isn't running the getter because nothing is actively getting the computed property.

#### So Why Do `data` Object Setters Trigger Getters Automatically?

The question I'm left with, then, is why Example #2 works the way that it does. In standard JavaScript, running a setter doesn't trigger the getter to execute, and this is by design, since getters and setters are just object properties that are bound to functions:

```js
var obj = {
  log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  get last() {
    console.log('Ran Getter, val:', this.log[this.log.length - 1]);
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  },
  set last(x) {
    console.log('Ran Setter, val:', x);
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1] = x;
  },
};

obj.last;        // Trigger Getter
obj.last = 'z';  // Trigger Setter
obj.last;        // Trigger Getter
obj.last;        // Trigger Getter
obj.last = 'y';  // Trigger Setter
obj.last = 'w';  // Trigger Setter
```

Therefore, I think that the behavior that you see with a getter/ setter pair defined in an object in `data` in Vue is actually a byproduct of Vue's reactivity scheme. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059477/defining-user-defined-getters-in-a-vue-component/51060426#51060426) walks through the nature of Vue's handling of preexisting getters, and so I imagine it's just how Vue handles making them reactive, by forcing the getters to recalculate when their dependencies change, rather than doing it when they're invoked.

#### Conclusion

Honestly, I would advise avoiding getters and setters in `data` if they aren't explicitly useful, since it heavily increases complexity and the potential for unexpected behavior. You can move getters to `computed` and setters to `methods`, which are essentially the Vue equivalents of getters and setters on the component level. Your components will almost certainly be easier to understand and debug in the future if you split the get/ set functionality out into the component!

---

Also wanted to note: you discovered that you can force the getter to run with `await this.$nextTick();`, but simply referencing the computed property before each assignment works as well, and results in the same log output as Example #2:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Hello!",
    myPropInternal: 0,
  },
  computed: {
    myProp: {
      // getter
      get: function() {
        console.log('get', this.myPropInternal);
        return this.myPropInternal;
      },
      // setter
      set: function(value) {
        console.log('set', value);
        this.myPropInternal = value;
      }
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.myProp; // Simply referencing the property activates the getter
    this.myProp = 1;
    this.myProp;
    this.myProp = 2;
    this.myProp;
    this.myProp = 3;
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message }} - {{ myProp }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank you! I was aware of optimization protecting DOM to be re-rendered, but I somehow expected that it will be optimized only when read by template or in some level in-between. This question is highly extracted from app and I need to check whether I did not make bad extraction. I will do later. But at least I get some new knowledge and I thank you for it. 

Answer (score 1):

1st example is standard Vue computed and it works as expected.

Point of Vue computed is to minimize the number of times the function (getter of the computed property) needs to be executed. So anytime the setter is executed, Vue just mark the current value (previously returned by getter) as dirty but it does not execute getter immediately! Because it is not needed! The getter gets executed next time someone (anyone! not just template/render function) tries to read the value...

Now to second example. First please notice how computed prop is defined in 1st example. You are giving Vue an object with two properties - `get` and `set`. You are not defining new property (in [JavaScript language sense](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)). Vue do that itself and just use your functions together with it's own code to create behavior described above...

But in second example you are using JS construct to create a new object property with predefined getter and setter. And use that object as reactive data inside Vue component. This is **very different** from Vue computed properties

Answer (score -1):

My coleague plays a bit with this examples and find out that if you puts $nextTick() between setting values you will got desired result

```js
  created: async function() {
    this.myProp = 1;
    await this.$nextTick();
    this.myProp = 2;
    await this.$nextTick();
    this.myProp = 3;
  }
```

could be for optimalisation of redraws, but if it so then IMHO it is done on wrong layer.. because I can use/reuse computed values even for internal controller logic and then this optimalisation is not desired.

So it could be optimized in result render function instead. Even Example2 shows that it is done on wrong layer as it is bypassing this optimalisation.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree that this optimization is "undesired," since it's doing *zero* redraws– you're calling this in [the `created` lifecycle hook, which executes fully before render](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#created). The component doesn't render until between the `beforeMount` and `mounted` hooks ([Vue Lifecycle Diagram](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)).

Comment: I haven't been able to dig up source(s) yet, but I think the behavior in question makes sense, because there's no need for Vue to call the computed setter until it actually renders it in the template. What I don't know for sure is why it *does* call the setter if it's just in the object/ data itself.

Comment: ok, but still there is inconsistency, because it is not optimized in second example and when I put some third party object into data and do not know its implementation it can lead to very hardly detected bugs :/